# SQL-only method of pulling as many characters as possible from a CLOB without overflowing the 4KB limit of varchar2 datatype

Tags: oracle

Here's a problem I've faced off and on over the years. It can be solved in PL/SQL easily enough but would like to put it out there to see if anyone knows a reasonable sane SQL-only solution:

When we want to get the largest amount of text possible (4000 bytes) from a CLOB that can be stored in a SQL varchar2 column. Obvious first choice is `SUBSTR`:

```
SUBSTR(clob,1,4000)
```

**This will error if there is any multibyte character that pushes the *byte* length beyond 4000.** So, we try `SUBSTRB` instead:

```
SUBSTRB(clob,1,4000)
```

**This will error (if over a dblink) or result in incomplete byte fragments if the 4000th byte is part of a multibyte character that also involves the 4001st byte, as that would split it.**

We need to maximize the # of characters extracted without passing the 4000 byte limit. What seems to be lacking is **a function that returns as many of the first 4000 bytes as it can without splitting any multibyte character up**. Or alternatively, return as many characters as fit within 4000 bytes. As far as I know there is no such function.

It cannot easily be calculated in a single formula (that I can think of) because the byte length of every character position would need to be considered in the proper order, not the byte length of the whole, requiring progressive testing that would imply the need for a loop or recursion.

In PL/SQL we can of course use a PL/SQL varchar2 of greater length and progressively add characters to it in a loop until it would surpass 4000 bytes of storage. Or start at 4000 characters and progressively remove characters until it's under 4000 bytes of storage. But clearly this is not a performant/optimal or convenient mechanism for employing with high frequency in SQL.

Another technique is to assume that multibyte characters will be rare and so guess at the amount of characters that are safe, like 3900 or 3500, and just take a risk. But some day you'll hit text entirely in Chinese or something and it'll bite you, plus you are cutting shorter than necessary every other value. The only safe way to do this in a 4-byte characterset is to use `SUBSTR(clob,1,1000)` which significantly shortens the amount of text that can be stored, just because of the *possibility* that they are all 4-byte characters (which would be extremely rare).

Any tricks out there that can provide a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've solved it. When `SUBSTRB` splits a multibyte character the incomplete byte fragments aren't random junk as I originally thought - they are converted into multiple single-byte `CHR(32)` characters (spaces). This means they can easily be trimmed away after conversion.

If in PL/SQL, it would then be as simple as:

```
var_varchar2 := RTRIM(SUBSTRB(dbms_lob.substr(var_lob,4000,1),1,4000),' ');
```

The `RTRIM` being the key to the clean-up and preventing character overflow if inserting into a column defined with character semantics.

In SQL, because of the lack of a `dbms_lob.substrb` function, we do still have to use a function call but it can be as simple as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clob_4000(in_clob IN clob)
  RETURN varchar2
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN RTRIM(SUBSTRB(dbms_lob.substr(in_clob,4000,1),1,4000),' ');
END;
```

Now test it:

```
create table tmp1 (clobcol clob);
create table tmp2 (col1 varchar2(4000));

DECLARE
  var_value clob;
BEGIN
  var_value := '... clipped 3000 bytes of 3-byte Chinese characters ...';
  
  var_value := var_value || '... clipped 3000 more bytes of 3-byte Chinese characters ...';
                             
  INSERT INTO tmp1 values (var_value);
  COMMIT;
END;

insert into tmp2 select clob_4000(clobcol) from tmp1;
commit;

SELECT dump(col1)
  FROM tmp2;
```

-- Result shows 3999 bytes and no junk at the end.

**Edit:**

If you want to preserve any trailing spaces that are actually part of the text itself, you can translate spaces to a impossible character (e.g. a device control byte like `CHR(20)` or something similar) and then translate those back to spaces at the end:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clob_4000(in_clob IN clob)
  RETURN varchar2
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN REPLACE(RTRIM(SUBSTRB(REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(in_clob,4000,1),' ',CHR(20)),1,4000),' '),CHR(20),' ');
END;
```

Comment: The only problem with this is if the 3999th character is a space and then you will trim that too. If you aren't worried about keeping trailing spaces then this works. If you are then you may need to add a check in PL/SQL to see whether its a split multi-byte character.

Comment: @MT0, I think in any case where someone is willing to take only the first 4000 chars of a longer text they wouldn't mind losing a trailing space at the end.

Comment: You would hope that is true but in the extreme edge-case when there are 3997 space characters and then a 4-byte character the function would return `NULL` (as all the spaces would be trimmed). I really doubt that trailing spaces would be significant but its worth signposting to people what the potential behaviour is so that if spaces do have a syntactic meaning to someone (or if they are expecting a non-`NULL` value) then they know they are going to have to add extra logic.

Comment: @mt0, edited with a fix for that